# How to sort array of object by key?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried this method:

```
if (field == 'age') {

      if (this.sortedAge) {
        this.fltUsers.sort(function (a, b) {
          if (b.totalHours > a.totalHours) {
            return 1;
          }
        });

        this.sortedAge = false;

      } else {

        this.sortedAge = true;
        this.fltUsers.sort(function (a, b) {
          if (b.totalHours < a.totalHours) {
            return 1;
          }
        });

      }
    }
```

So I have array of objects. Each object has property: `totalHours`.

I need to order this array by desc/asc this field `totalHours` after click.

My code does not work.

Comment: This is hard to tell without actually seeing the array, it's also most likely a duplicate. Anyway, you're only returning *if* something happens, you should be returning `1`, `-1` or `0` depending on the comparison.

Comment: `this.fltUsers.sort((a, b) => a.totalHours - b.totalHours)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code must sort the array.

```
  function compare(a,b) {
      if (b.totalHours < a.totalHours)
        return -1;
      if (b.totalHours > a.totalHours)
        return 1;
      return 0;
  }

  objects.sort(compare);
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually follow 1-line rule for the kind of simple comparator like yours, so I would modify it like this

```
this.fltUsers.sort((a,b) => b.totalHours < a.totalHours ? 1 : -1);
```

You need at least `1` and `-1` returned so that the comparator logic can work.